# How to change the language select link dinamically using thymeleaf and spring internacionalization

Tags: java, spring, internationalization, thymeleaf

I'm developing a website which must have internationalization and I'm trying to change the Language Select Text to make it render dynamically according to the language the user is using right now.

Let's say the website is in Portuguese right now, then the Language Select Text should read 'English' and the value should change accordingly and vice-versa.

The code as it is right now:

```
<select class="form-control dropdown2 col-lg-2 col-10 text-white" id="locales">
      <option>Idioma/Language</option>
      <option value="en" th:text="#{langEN}"></option>
      <option value="pt_BR" th:text="#{langPT}"></option>
</select>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#locales").change(function() {
        var selectedOption = $('#locales').val();
        if (selectedOption != '') {
            window.location.replace('?lang=' + selectedOption);
        }
        if(document.getElementById("clientPage")){
            window.location.replace(window.location.href + '&lang=' + selectedOption);
        }
    });
});
```

And here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<a th:href="#{langURL}" th:text="#{lang}"></a>
```

where both `langURL` and `lang` will be set at message.properties in each language.

**EDIT:**

My problem was solved using the following code:

```
<a th:href="@{/?lang=}+#{lang.url}" th:text=#{lang.text}></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you have created all the Beans that should be created to achieve this, so I will provide as much help as I can so someone can configure Spring + Thymeleaf from scratch.

First set the localResolver bean and set a default locale:

```
@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
    slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
    return slr;
}
```

Then, in your @Configuration class (which should implement the WebMvcConfigurer interface) set the localeChangeInterceptor so it changes the language based on the `lang` parameter of each request:

```
@Bean
public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    lci.setParamName("lang");
    return lci;
}
```

And set the interceptor in application's interceptor registry:

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
}
```

Thats all for Spring configuration. Now you need to add messages.properties files into your src/main/resources folder. The language is set in the messages.properties filename using the following format: messages_??.properties, where ?? is the language code, e.g.: messages_en.properties or messages_fr.properties.

Also note that if a language code (lang parameter) does not exist as an existing locale, then the application will fall back to the default locale. value.

Finally, make sure that your URLs include the parameter `lang=<language>` i.e. `http://example.com/page?lang=fr`

Comment: I should've added more information, thanks for your time and attention.
My problem was solved using your suggestion and the following code:


`<a th:href="@{/?lang=}+#{lang.url}" th:text=#{lang.text}></a>`